Pointwise multiplication of modules homomorphism in noncommutative case
Let $A$ be a noncommutative (unital associative) ring and $M,N$ be left $A$-modules. It's well known that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is an Abelian group with respect to the pointwise addition.
But why it is not possible to define left $A$-module structure on this group (unlike commutative case) as $$a*f: \  m\mapsto af(m).$$ What's exactly wrong with that "multiplication"? I guess that $a*f$ is not linear? If so, what is a concrete example when linearity fails?

$a*f$ may no longer be $A$-linear:
$$(a*f)(bm)=af(bm)=a(b(f(m))=(ab)f(m)\stackrel{?}{=}b(a*f)(m)=b(af(m))=(ba)f(m)$$

There exists an obvious counter example:
Let $A=R\langle x, y, z\rangle$ for some commutative ring $R$ (i.e. $A$ is a free associative algebra over $R$) and let $M=N=A$ treated as a left $A$-module (i.e. $M$ is a left regular $A$-module). Consider $f\in \operatorname{Hom}_A(M, N)$, $f(m):=xm$. Then $$(y*f)(z)=yf(z)=yzf(1)=yzx,$$ while $$z(y*f)(1)=zyx\neq yzx.$$
